# Error Running script with shell_exec from custom controller

Tags: magento-1.9

I created a script that I run off a CSV of which I manipulate the data and create a new CSV (for imports through magmi).

When I run it through the command line it goes without a hitch.

I then proceeded to create a custom module on my magento site to allow the client to upload the csv from the admin.
[image: This is how it looks from the backend]

I then have a controller that moves the uploaded file to my script and proceed to call shell_exec which I assumed would be doing exactly what I did when running from the command line.

Instead i got the following error

> PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function snappy_uncompress() in /chroot/home/mywebsite.com/html/lib/Cm/Cache/Backend/Redis.php on line 888

I believe this is due to the fact that my script is loading Mage.

This is my controller:

```
    public function postAction(){
    if($_POST){

        //Get target directory and file name
        $upOne = substr(getcwd(), 0, strrpos( getcwd(), '/')  );
        $targetDir = $upOne . '/MyScriptDirectory/';
        $targetFile = $_FILES['myFile']['name'];

        //Upload file
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'], $targetDir . $targetFile)) {
           // Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Success');
        } else {
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Failed to upload file');
        }

        //Run script with $targetFile as argument 
        exec (  "cd SunberryImport/ && php main.php "  . $targetFile. " 2>&1",$output, $val );

        //Get output and print to screen
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError(implode($output));

    }
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

When I moved my script within the magento application and stopped loading mage within the script I no longer got that error.

I rather keep my script separate from the main application.

Is the problem due to running mage twice in the same php session?

> Sorry if I'm not being clear I'm new to both magento and this is my first Magento stack overflow question.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, welcome to StackExchange!

I'm really curious why you want to import the CSV using a shell script. Can't you import it via PHP? Because the script you run now is far from secure. Theoretically, if I call my file `; && rm -rf /`, it will actually run this command on your command line, with all terrible consequences from there.

I'd suggest to see if you can change this into importing via a regular way by either importing a CSV via a custom importer or maybe you can refactor it so you can use the default Magento importer (see: https://trellis.co/blog/uploading-products-magento-product-excel/).

Last but not least, you could check your code by using default Magento code, like the file uploader (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734281/magento-image-upload-form-field) and the way to check for post `if ($this->getRequest()->getPost()`.

Hope this will help you along.

Comment: Thank Argen. Would that be called command ingection? : )
I could just rename the file and pass that in as my argument.

Comment: I'd still not run a command line script based for an action in the browser, since you have way more possibilities and permissions when running a script in the browser. So if possible I'd suggest to use a PHP based import script.